# Can't paste into merged cell using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, merge

I'm writing a macro that copies data to a template form, saves the form under a different name, and then copies using the same blank form. Some of the data is copied into merged cells. Weirdly enough, the code that I am currently using works for the first, second, and third iteration, but not the fourth.

I've tried everything I can think of but it still won't work. It gives me the error message "We can't do that to a merged cell".

Here is the code that won't paste into the cell.

```
'     
' Transfers Component 1 Data
'
    Range("B27").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Protected_Form.xls").Activate
    Range("B61:D61").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

And here is the code that DOES paste into the merged cell earlier on in the program:

```
'
' Transfers Component 1 Data
'
    Range("AV194").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Protected_Form.xls").Activate
    Range("B61:D61").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

As you can see, the only thing that changes is what cell the data is being copied from.

Edit:
Just realized that I used the same code(the part that isn't working) early on in the program under certain conditions. I just tried running it under those conditions and it worked.

Now I'm extremely confused. Feel free to ask me to clarify things, I know this is confusing.

Also: I know `.Select`. is slow, I don't care.

Comment: The error speaks for itself. Either in your source or in the destination workbook, you have a merged cell.

Comment: Other parts of the program paste into merged cells.

Comment: Just saw your edit, are you still having the same issue?

Comment: Have you tried fully qualifying your range references?  Perhaps earlier in the program Range("B27").Select is selecting on one sheet and Range("B27").Select is selecting from a different sheet later on.

Also, and not to harp on it but... .Select is not only slow, it also tends to lead to unexpected results, which I suspect is the issue you're having now.

Comment: You mentioned that the same code works "under some conditions" - what are those conditions? Also, which cells are merged? Are there times when some of the copied cells are also merged?

Comment: @sous2817 You were right! Thank god. I had to activate the spreadsheet I was referencing. Also, I really wish I could get away from select, but I'm learning VBA on the fly for a project at work and don't have the luxury.

Comment: Great, glad I could help!  I'll add it as an answer, which you're more than welcome to accept if you found it helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried fully qualifying your range references? Perhaps earlier in the program Range("B27").Select is selecting on one sheet and Range("B27").Select is selecting from a different sheet later on.

Also, and not to harp on it but... .Select is not only slow, it also tends to lead to unexpected results, which I suspect is the issue you're having now. I know you said in a comment that you don't have time (luxury) to get away from it, but the time spent cleaning up your code now will save you TONS of time if you ever have to debug, change, modify, update, etc. I wouldn't look at it as a chore, but a necessity to writing good VBA code!